# Pivoting a defined number of rows into columns according to a common column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following set of data in my table in SQL Server as follows:

```
Table Name: Metadata

IdMetadata  IdMetadataKey   Value                   IdBatch
1           3               50550000                105
2           2               ABC                     105
3           5               Buks                    105
4           1               Bruwer                  105
5           4               AB1234567/4             105
6           6               Annuity Tax Directive   105
7           3               50594644                105
8           2               ABC                     105
9           5               Jami                    105
10          1               Leigh                   105
11          4               9401213056080           105
12          6               Redemption              105
13          3               50550026                106
14          2               ABC                     106
15          5               John                    106
16          1               Smith                   106
17          4               6812305023089           106
18          6               Tax Free Transfer Out   106
```

The column values in IdMetadataKey is a foreign key pointing to the following primary table

```
Table Name: MetadataKey

IdMetadataKey   Description
1               LAST_NAME
2               COMPANY
3               INVESTOR_ID
4               IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER
5               FIRST_NAME
6               WORK_DESCRIPTION
```

What I want to accomplish using the first table I mentioned above is the following:

```
Investor_Id First_Name  Last_Name   ID_Number    Work_Description       Company IdBatch
50550000    Buks        Bruwer      AB1234567/4  Annuity Tax Directive  ABC     105
50594644    Jami        Leigh       555254       Redemption             ABC     105
50550026    John        Smith       9958586      Tax Free Transfer Out  ABC     106
```

The explanation for the above result goes like this:

1. Take the IdBatch 105, find all investors and its relevant
   information for that batch. Hence the 2 records for batch 105
2. The same goes for IdBatch 106. But here only one record (investor)
   is found

I have tried using the `Pivot` command in SQL to achieve that result, but couldn't get it to work. Can anyone suggest a way to get the desired result.

Side note: there would always be 6 (* n) rows for a batch in table Metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with static pivot in sql server. In my opinion it will be a better approach to join both tables to get the column header for pivot table instead of mentioning them in query hard codedly.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table metadata(IdMetadata int, IdMetadataKey int,  Value varchar(50), IdBatch int);
 insert into metadata values(1,           3               ,'50550000',                105);
 insert into metadata values(2,           2               ,'ABC',                     105);
 insert into metadata values(3,           5               ,'Buks',                    105);
 insert into metadata values(4,           1               ,'Bruwer',                  105);
 insert into metadata values(5,           4               ,'AB1234567/4',             105);
 insert into metadata values(6,           6               ,'Annuity Tax Directive',   105);
 insert into metadata values(7,           3               ,'50594644',                105);
 insert into metadata values(8,           2               ,'ABC',                     105);
 insert into metadata values(9,           5               ,'Jami',                    105);
 insert into metadata values(10,          1               ,'Leigh',                   105);
 insert into metadata values(11,          4               ,'9401213056080',           105);
 insert into metadata values(12,          6               ,'Redemption',              105);
 insert into metadata values(13,          3               ,'50550026',                106);
 insert into metadata values(14,          2               ,'ABC',                     106);
 insert into metadata values(15,          5               ,'John',                    106);
 insert into metadata values(16,          1               ,'Smith',                   106);
 insert into metadata values(17,          4               ,'6812305023089',           106);
 insert into metadata values(18,          6               ,'Tax Free Transfer Out',   106);


 create table MetadataKey(IdMetadataKey int,   Description varchar(50));
 insert into MetadataKey values(1,               'LAST_NAME');
 insert into MetadataKey values(2,               'COMPANY');
 insert into MetadataKey values(3,               'INVESTOR_ID');
 insert into MetadataKey values(4,               'IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER');
 insert into MetadataKey values(5,               'FIRST_NAME');
 insert into MetadataKey values(6,               'WORK_DESCRIPTION');
```

Query:

```
 select max(Investor_Id)Investor_Id, max(First_Name)First_Name,  max(Last_Name)Last_Name,   max(IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER),    max(Work_Description)Work_Description,       max(Company)Company, max(IdBatch)IdBatch
 from
 (
   select md.*, mdk.Description,row_number()over(partition by idbatch,md.idmetadatakey order by idmetadata)rnk from metadata md inner join metadatakey mdk on md.idMetadataKey=mdk.idMetadataKey
 ) As SourceTable
 Pivot
 (
 max(value) for Description in (Investor_Id, First_Name,  Last_Name,   IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER,    Work_Description,       Company)
 ) as P
 Group by IdBatch,rnk
 order by idbatch,investor_id
```

Output:

| Investor_Id | First_Name | Last_Name | (No column name) | Work_Description | Company | IdBatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50550000 | Buks | Bruwer | AB1234567/4 | Annuity Tax Directive | ABC | 105 |
| 50594644 | Jami | Leigh | 9401213056080 | Redemption | ABC | 105 |
| 50550026 | John | Smith | 6812305023089 | Tax Free Transfer Out | ABC | 106 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2da195d8d55566e64830cabc6c87641a)*

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use conditional aggregation to "pivot" your rows to columns. You know you always have the same columns so you can simply use `case` to select the value for each column.

Note, your sample output (ID_Number) doesn't quite match your sample data, assuming this is just a sample data preparation oversight.

You also need an additional column to group Investor_Id together.

```
select
  max(case idMetadataKey when 3 then value end) Investor_Id,
  max(case idMetadataKey when 5 then value end) First_Name,
  max(case idMetadataKey when 1 then value end) Last_Name,
  max(case idMetadataKey when 4 then value end) Id_Number,
  max(case idMetadataKey when 6 then value end) Work_Description,
  max(case idMetadataKey when 2 then value end) Company,
 IDBatch
from (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by idbatch, IdMetadataKey order by IdMetadata) grp
    from Metadatad 
)m
group by IDBatch, grp
order by IDBatch, grp
```

See this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7d27ddf0e96ddfb4df4866a2bc26016)